# visual studio 2022 .net project reference with wrong package version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, package, version, project-reference

I have updated the ef core package in my ServiceModel Project from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1 due to installing ef tools.
This resulted in a compiler error stating that there is a missmatch in ef core versions between my main project and the ServiceModel.
I checked both .csproj files and both have version 6.0.1 for ef core.

In Visual Studio 2022 I see that there is the wrong package referenced in the project reference (6.0.0 for ServiceModel). But only in the project reference of another project...

[image: Wrong Reference in VS2022]

Is there some cache from Visual Studio or nuget that keeps the references and I need to clear?